# Unable to open device node from userspace in android

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, android-drm

In android, I am getting issues in opening the device node(dev/dri/card0) from hwcomposer working in userspace. I am trying to opening the device like:

```
fd_ = open("/dev/dri/card0", O_RDWR);
if (fd_ < 0) {
    ALOGE("Failed to open dri- %s", strerror(-errno));
    return -ENODEV;
}
```

Error:

```
hwc-drm-resources: Failed to open dri- Unknown error -13
```

Error 13 is permission access issues. For that i have configured the permission in ueventd.rc in android:

```
/dev/dri/*                0666   root       graphics
```

I have also tried setting the permission to system system. It still not working.

When i run ls -la in /dev/dri. It shows the following output, it have rw permission for user mode.

```
crw-rw-rw- root     graphics 226,   0 2015-01-01 00:26 card0
crw-rw-rw- root     graphics 226,  64 2015-01-01 00:26 controlD64
```

I don't understand why hwcomposer won't be able to access the device node, Since the permission are set for the device node.

Comment: Tip: Correct using of `strerror` is passing *unmodified* (not negated) value of `errno` to it: `sterror(errno)`. As for accessing problems, it is possible that device itself rejects all accesses to it from user without some capabilities.

Comment: What are the permissions for **/dev/dri** (i.e. the directory)?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. I forgot to put the entry for the device nodes in /external/sepolicy.

```
/dev/dri(/.*)?         u:object_r:graphics_device:s0
```

More information about sepolicy is given on the android website.
https://source.android.com/security/selinux/implement.html.